# Connect an C# application thats running sockets using JAVASCRIPT

Tags: c#, javascript, android

Hey i was wondering if you could help me

I'm creating an android application in html5 and java script.
There are a server that is created on c# that is listing connection.
 I can connect the 2 apps together but get i can get the c# app to reply to my android application using javascript.

here is my server code

```
    public void Listeners()
    {
        Socket socketForClient = tcpListener.AcceptSocket();
        if (socketForClient.Connected)
        {
            nr_connections = nr_connections + 1;
            nr_qry = nr_qry + 1;
            SetText("");
            SetText("New Connection.");
            NetworkStream networkStream = new NetworkStream(socketForClient);
            StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(networkStream);
            StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(networkStream);
            streamWriter.Flush();
            string GettheString = streamReader.ReadLine();
            if (GettheString == "server_status")
            {
                SetText("Checking Server Status.");
                streamWriter.WriteLine("Online");
                streamWriter.Close();
                streamReader.Close();
                networkStream.Close();
            }
        }
        socketForClient.Close();
        SetText("Connection Closed...");
        Thread newThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Listeners));
        newThread.Start();
        nr_connections = nr_connections - 1;
    }
```

and my javascript code

```
function connect ()
{
  try
  {
      var connection = new WebSocket('ws://105.237.125.247:8');

      connection.onopen = function () 
      {
         connection.send('server_status');
      };
      connection.onmessage = function (event) {
          alert(event.data);
      }
  } 
  catch(Exeption)
  {
      alert("Check Connection");
  }
}
```

Im getting data from the android app but can send back to the javascript file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Web-sockets is a protocol that *sits on top of* a regular transport (such as a socket); basically, you need a web-socket library. If you are using recent versions of Windows, then much of this is baked into HTTP.SYS, and available via `HttpListnener` (in particular, `AcceptWebSocketAsync` on a context). However, alternative web-socket libraries are available, or can be written from scratch if you so choose.

Comment: Thank you. It was not the answer i was looking for but you pointed me in the right direction. I got my code to work now tanx